# Python code not able to extract rows from large csv files

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to extract rows as per different values from different files in the given folder. For example value1 from file1, value2 from file 2 and value3 from file3. Please find my code below. This code is working; however, its not able to extract rows from large csv files , in this case the code is successful for 4kb, 9kb file but not from 3.8 mb file(its not huge). Can you please help here.

```
import glob, os
import pandas as pd

def clean_files(input_folder_path,output_folder_path, input_trade):
     
        #get the list of all csv files in the given folder
        files =[file for file in os.listdir(input_folder_path) if file.endswith('INTEREST_RATE_SWAP_OTC_20231019.csv')]
        #print(files)
        
        #initialize an empty dataframe to store the combined results
        rows = pd.DataFrame()
        #loop through each file and read it into a pandas df
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(input_folder_path,file)
           
            #ignore first 5 rows as they are not relevant
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path,skiprows = 5,low_memory=False)

            #data cleaning
            df1 = df.iloc[:-1,:-2].set_axis(df.columns[2:], axis=1)
            clean_data = df1.drop(df1.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace = False)
          
            #search the single trade id in the files
            for trades in input_trade:
                trade_rows = clean_data[clean_data['TRADE_ID'] == trades]
                print(trade_rows)
                if not trade_rows.empty:
                   rows = rows._append(trade_rows, ignore_index = True)    
              
        #write the combined results to a new csv file in the output folder
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, f"FIXCF_NH3.csv")
        rows.to_csv(output_file_path,index = False)
        #if need only write to file omit return cleaned_df
        return clean_data
```

Comment: Is there are reason you're setting `low_memory=False` in `pd.read_csv()`? Have you tried without? Also, how is it failing? Does it error out, hang, finish without errors but didn't proccess the file?

Comment: @CalebMcNevin...no difference with True or False. Finishes without errors ; it does read the big file but doesnt extract the rows from it.

Comment: What kind of output do you get from your print statement `print(trade_rows)`? Does it reach that point and print anything, or does it exit without any output?

Comment: As a result of `data cleaning`, the names of the columns in the dataframe are shifted, do you know about this?

Comment: @CalebMcNevin... i get the rows which are extracted from the files as per the value.

Comment: @СергейКох... yes... thats my requirement to shift the columns . Its working fine for all the files but only issue is that its not extracting the rows from bigger files.